# Printing on a Pre-Printed Form in .net

Tags: .net

Pleasant Day!. I'm trying to find out how to print on a pre-printed form.

[image: Sample form]

The image above shows the data that i want to print on my pre-printed form, the Stock Withdrawal List i'm kinda new to .net and i need an idea where to start, below is my pre-printed form, any advice or tips on what i should use would be much appreciated.

[image: Pre-printed form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution but it was hard, but i got what i wanted

```
Dim font1 As New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim ctrl As Integer = 0
        Dim nextline As Integer = 0

        Do
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_request_number.Text, New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 530, 182)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_div.Text, New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 110, 162)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_purpose.Text, New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 101, 457)


            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_requested_by.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 134, 535)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_requested_by.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 134, 555)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Mainform.txt_date_now.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 134, 575)


            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_ra.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 240, 535)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_ra_pos.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 240, 555)


            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_gm_name.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 380, 535)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_gm_position.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 380, 555)


            e.Graphics.DrawString(Mainform.txt_uname.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 550, 535)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Mainform.txt_designation.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 550, 555)


            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_requested_by.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 670, 535)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_requested_by.Text, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 670, 555)


            e.Graphics.DrawString(lv_m_requestioned.Items(ctrl).SubItems(0).Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 62, 254 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lv_m_requestioned.Items(ctrl).SubItems(1).Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 195, 254 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lv_m_requestioned.Items(ctrl).SubItems(2).Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 370, 254 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lv_m_requestioned.Items(ctrl).SubItems(3).Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 110, 254 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lv_m_requestioned.Items(ctrl).SubItems(4).Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 140, 254 + nextline)
            nextline = nextline + 20
            ctrl = ctrl + 1
        Loop Until ctrl = lv_m_requestioned.Items.Count
```